# background won't show: can i put a background upon a back ground in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a rails site https://cherry-cupcake-30790.herokuapp.com/

and i have a background green going into white. i have in the middle of this a white area where i want to put another background to the text in this area. i have tried adding bamboo.jg with the following line added into the css file.

```
background-image: url(/assets/bamboo.jpg);
```

i have also tried variations on this

```
background-image: url(/images/bamboo.jpg);
background-image: url(bamboo.jpg);
background-image: url("bamboo.jpg");
background: url(bamboo.jpg);
```

and a few others but the background still doesn't show. Any ideas why?

Comment: In what folder is the image located? Does your asset pipeline in general work for other file types?

Comment: assest/images/bamboo;jpg

Comment: Is the css in a different folder or is the assets folder a directory above it then make sure to use background-image: url("../images/bamboo.jpg");

Comment: @Rafaël De Jongh the css is also in the assets folder in the stylesheets folder i.e. assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss and assets/images/bamboo.jpg

Comment: If it is then you would indeed have to say to the css stylesheet that it has to go one folder up and then back to images/bamboo.jpg. 

The best way to check this is by looking in your console/developers tools, see what the current path is of your url, then you can probably figure it out what you've done wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your css file is processed by Sprockets by using the `.css.scss` or the `.css.sass` file extension. Within this file use the following syntax:

```
background-image: image-url("bamboo.jpg")
```

Read about the [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) in the Rails Guides.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? Is there any application exception? What does browser try to fetch when you open page? You can see it in web console or web inspector.

Comment: What URL does this line render into your css file?

Comment: it doesnt work by the image not showing. there is no error and the text appears fine.

Comment: @spickermann. i dont understand your question. what do you mean by "render"?

Comment: I want to known how the CSS looks like that is generated by the server when running the app? What happens if you request that generated URL from the CSS?